# Can you skip a count in a for loop without an if statement

Tags: r, loops

Is there code that can let me skip numbers/counts in a for loop.

```
for (i in 2:100){ 
    argument
}
```

but I want to skip every ten .. so check 1-9 skip 10 and go to 11 ... skip 20 .. go to 21 .. skip another number 47 (there is no pattern to the skipped numbers in the count)etc?

Comment: Just specify the numbers you want to check instead of `2:100`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like below, which excludes `10`,`20` and `47` from `2:100`

```
for (i in (v <- 2:100)[!v %in% c(10,20,47)]){ 
    argument
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`next`

```
for (i in 2:10){ 
  if (i %in% c(4) || i %% 5 == 0) next
  cat(i)
}
```

In the above example you skip 4 and numbers divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset those to exclude.

For the loop counts:

```
for (i in (2:100)[-c(10,20,47)]) {
  #argument
}
```

or for `i` as you start at 2.

```
for (i in (2:100)[-c(10,20,47)+1]) {
  #argument
}
```